# Python in Visual Studio Giving Unresolved Import

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip

I am trying to use Visual Studio 2019 Community edition to edit a Python script. However, it gives "Unresolved import" errors even though they are loaded (through the pip installer) and show in the project management screen. I have searched this site and Googled this but haven't seen an answer for this case.

Has anyone experienced this and how was it fixed?

The following is a screen shot of the errors.

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to this question, I rebooted my Windows computer. When I reopened this project, the "Unresolved import" errors went away. It runs just fine now. Is there anything rebooting can't fix?

Comment: Your comment rescued me. Post it as answer and I'll upvote :-)

Comment: Welp, I'm on VS 2022 (17.5.0) and reboot won't do a thing :( Project runs fine.